# Webapp for drafting comic strip chat bubbles

Tags: web-apps

I'm looking to fulfill the following workflow:

- Draft comic panels and chat bubbles in my browser.

  - Chat bubbles, action bubbles, thought bubbles, etc.
  - Upload font-files.
  - Edit text bubbles
- The webapp is probably a mouse based WYSIWYG, but I could work with something less obvious.

  - For example, I'm willing to learn a yaml/toml style syntax if the software author thought that was easier than programming drag-n-drop and other mouse actions.
- The webapp has templates for different comic types (standard 3-panel, 4-panel, 6-panel for me, manga, and other type templates for other users).
- Save the drafts in something like Google Drive or Dropbox
- Export in high resolution without a watermark

  - should support a standard or normal format with transparency, like PNG or PSD
- Use exported files as an upper layer in other software like GIMP, Krita, drawing tablet, Adobe, etc.

If the software does not already exist, I might write it myself.

Answer (score 0):

https://gramener.com/comicgen/

Comicgen is an opensource tool and while I have not used it myself yet, I came across it while searching for something similar to your requirements. See if it is helpful.

Comment: This seems to be the opposite of what I'm looking for. It has a very basic character designer and appears to have no functionality for drafting chat bubbles.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you. It's not exactly what you are looking for but it's definitely worth a look.

[Photopea](https://www.photopea.com/) is like Photo Shop in the browser. You could create a file with you basic items (in hidden layers) and edit/copy this file and build new images from your items.